# Help Required! Changing Subscribed Topics of a Package

Tags: ros, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greeting friends, I am currently working on a low cost method of mapping and I have decided to use ultrasonic to do it.

Ultrasonic Range Package: https://github.com/sharvashish/Obstacle_detection__HCSR04

Mapping Package: http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

The problem is the ultrasonic publishes a "sensor" topic while the mapping subscribes to "scan".
Is there a method to make the mapping package subscribe to "sensor" instead?

Cheers, Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274738/help-required!-changing-subscribed-topics-of-a-package/) by [AllanXyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32465/allanxyl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a question of semantics. A single measurement is not directly equivalent to a "scan", at least the the type that `gmapping` is looking for (`LaserScan`). You'll have to find (or implement) a node that converts your ultrasonic range measurements into a (poor) `LaserScan` msg.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1